# Java REGEX pattern matching 2

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]=[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

I'm trying to make a pattern that will copy the PROPERTIES file format. But the code only works if the string before the equals sign is one character.

My ending goal is to have a pattern that will look like this: AnyLetterOrNumberInUndefinedAmount=AnyLetterOrNumberInUndefinedAmount

What can I do to fix my code.

Comment: So how do you get multiple characters? I mean you're already doing it further in your regex...

Comment: Why don't you just add a `+` before the `=` like you've done at the end?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it gives me a syntax error if I do that

Comment: _What_ gives you _which_ syntax error?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The part of the code that contains pattern code in my question returns a boolean based on if the String matches the pattern or not. Based on that boolean, an output message is produced telling me if the String matches the pattern or not. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Ok, so what is the syntax error?

Comment: But why the downvotes, this is a valid question? Is this question not beneficial?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis let me give you an example. I have this string: a=somthing

That String matches the pattern.

However, when I have a String like this: abc=somthing

That String doesn't match the pattern.

The error, im assuming, is within the pattern.

Comment: You're not understanding. In the regex you currently have, you used a `+`. What does that do?  You also said `it gives me a syntax error if I do that`. What does `that` refer to and what `syntax error` do you get?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, I misread your original comment. My knowledge on patterns and REGEX is small as is. After re-reading your comment I see what you meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `"^([^=]+)=(.+)$"`. This will place the expressions on either side of the equality sign in matching groups that you can retrieve later, and both will match everything except the first equality sign itself.

The + suffix means that both expressions must contain at least one character. If you want to be able to match nothing at all on either side, replace + with *.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for further explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a good reference to me, I'll look back at it when I run into more pattern problems.

Comment: Try this one. it is updated to Java SE 8
[Pattern Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Please explain why I need to add the + or * before the equal sign but not at the end?

Comment: i have edited * to + as * will take 0 or more such matching groups and + will take 1 or more such matching groups till = is encountered or match failed

Comment: for more and detailed info on quantifiers, you can visit:
[Quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Answer (score 1):

your pattern should be in "(^[a-zA-Z1-9]*)=(.*)"

Answer (score 1):

Right now your first character set/class only allows for `1` character of (`a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, `0` to `9`)

An easy fix and mistake, just add the `+` quantifier meaning (`1` or more times) after your character class.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
                                               ^
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/zG2vN7)

Comment: Yes, but could you explain why the pattern only allows for one instance of [a-zA-Z0-9] before the equals sign, but after the equals sign it can contain multiple instances?